# Proper use of VerifyText and VerifyElementPresent Commands

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In Selenium IDE script, I have to verify that an UI element is present on the page or not. This can be achieved by using `VerifyElementPresent` Command but when I am using `VerifyText` command with the locator of that UI element, the command just works fine and shows no log errors.

So, my question hear is what is the clear differentiation between these 2 commands, when the specified use of `VerifyElementPresent` Command could be achieved with `VerifyText` Command.

Comment: Well use `VerifyElementPresent` when you only care about it actually existing on the page, use the other one when you care for it existing on the page *and* having a certain text inside it.

Comment: But, when I could achieve the same thing with VerifyText Command, what is the use of VerifyElementPresent command. What is the clear difference between them. There must be something that made Selenium developers to make 2 different commands.

Comment: With VerifyText, Selenium has to verify the element and the text, whereas with VerifyElementPresent it doesnt have to verify the text. So there is an implementation and execution time difference involved. So if your requirement is to verify element presence then you use VerifyElement and save time otherwise use VerifyText if it is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TestAutomationEngr has explained it pretty clearly.

I'd look at this from a semantic perspective.

`VerifyText` and `VerifyElementPresent` are two very different functions which perform two very different actions.

I would define them both, but they are very self explanatory.

If your test says "make sure that this exists..." then you should use `VerifyElementPresent`.  Why would you use `VerifyText` even if it works?  Even when you read it back to yourself a year from now - you'd look at and say `wait... my AC says make sure it exists.. why did i call VerifyText?`

Think of it from the perspective of someone else, too.  They'd think the same thing. `Why'd this person call VerifyText if VerifyElementPresent is the command to verify that something exists?`.  To avoid confusion - use the methods that are provided to you.

Use `VerifyText` when you need to verify text, and use `VerifyElementPresent` when you need to make sure that something is present.  Simple as that.  Don't stray away from simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and help sircapsalot and TestAutomationEngr. It is simple and explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

VerifyText - Verifies the element text. 
whether the element has the text or not

VerifyTextPresent - verifies that the text is present or not in the entire current page source.
so we can say verifyText is the element specific form of verifyTextPresent